# ListView Item Open New Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm still following a couple of tutorials in order to learn Android Development, I am struggling to open new activities. I can open only one activity, in fact all items on my `ListView` open this one activity, which would be great for `ListView` item in position 0 (the first item) not all of them.

My code below:

```
        // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity1.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }        
    });

    return view;
}
```

As you can see MyActivity1.class opens fine, but what if I had a second class called MyActivity2 which should be opened up by listview item in position 1 (second item), how would I do that? Also what does (View arg0) mean? I can't find proper explanation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(n## Heading ##ew OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        if(position == 1) {
            //code specific to first list item    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Html_file1.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        if(position == 2) {
            //code specific to 2nd list item    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Html_file2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Down votter please comment the mistake.

Comment: solved, I was in fact expecting an "if" statement but wasn't sure how to go about it. This resolved my problem although myIntent could not be duplicated so I used myItent0 and myIntent1 etc... Thanks you all for your answers.

Comment: @TwoStarII so if you have 10 activities you will write that much if else statements?

Comment: @Raghunandan YES, that way I'm in control of each activity independently.

Comment: @TwoStarII and if you have 20 then 20 of the same. Nope. Check my code

Comment: @ Raghunandan - your code uses onItemClick, mine uses onClick, I couldn't convert my listener to onItemClick because I was extending BaseAdpater and not Activity, perhaps your code can bind classes or activities better but I'm still a newbie, once my knowledge improves I may revisit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use listview `OnItemClickListener`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
{
       @Override 
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
       { 
         switch(positon)
         {
             case 0:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity1.class);
                      mContext.startActivity(intent);
             break;
             case 1:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity2.class);
                      mContext.startActivity(intent);
             break;
         }  
       }
});
```

`position` is the index of list item. so based on the index you can start the respective activity.

The other way without switch case

```
String[] classes ={"MyActivity1","MyActivity2"};
```

Then in onItemClick

```
String value = classes[position];
Class ourClass =Class.forName("packagename."+value);
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,ourClass);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: and `View arg0` represents an instance of a `View` on which you clicked... such as `Button` and `ImageView`...

Comment: @GopalRao right. there is a better way without switch case

Comment: hmmmm... I just added additional explanation to your answer as OP asked what does `View arg0` represents...

Comment: `Class.forName("packagename"+value);` should be `Class.forName("packagename."+value);`... A dot after packagename

Comment: @GopalRao typo mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can use Itemclick listner.

```
listviewOBJ.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
{
       @Override 
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
       { 

       }
});
```

here you can use `int position` to decide which item is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, then here is your answer:

Implement `OnItemClickListener` to your main activity:
then set listener to your **listview**: `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

finallly :

```
    private OnItemClickListener mOnGalleryClick = new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


   switch(positon)
         {
             case 0:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity1.class);
                      mContext.startActivity(intent);
             break;
             case 1:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity2.class);
                      mContext.startActivity(intent);
             break;
         }  
        }       
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
```

`onClick` is called when you click on something, and `arg0` (you could call it `view`, `arg0` is so useless as name) is what you clicked.

This callback is often used in `Buttons`, `Views` in general but cannot be used with `ListView`.

If you want to open something when an item in the listview is clicked, you should use [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)!

On [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) you have `AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id` arguments.

From android doc:

- **parent**: The AdapterView where the click happened.
- **view**: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
- **position**: The position of the item clicked (0 the first, 1 the second etc.)
- **id**: The row id of the item that was clicked.

When you write your `onItemClick` you should remember you are in an anonymous class!
So you cannot use `this` when you need to pass your context to `new Intent`

```
pastesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                intent = new Intent(ActivityClass.this, Class1.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                intent = new Intent(ActivityClass.this, Class2.class);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

This line

```
ActivityClass.this
```

is used when you need to use the instance of the class `ActivityClass` (You should replace `ActivityClass` with your class name) but you cannot access it directly using `this` which here refer to `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`

In your code you use `mContext` i don't know what is it, but i suppose it's a context.

Next time you don't have this variable, follow my advise if you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

```
    final ListView list = ...;
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity1.class);
            if (position == 1) {
                intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity2.class);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```